# vuex: do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js, store

I have the following scenario:

Component Textfield:

```
<v-text-field
  v-model="form.profile.mobile_business"
  label="Mobile"
  prepend-inner-icon="mdi-cellphone"
></v-text-field>
```

I get the current value via:

```
data() {
        return {
            form: {
                profile: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.getters["user/Profile"])),
            },
        };
    },
```

I have a submit button that calls this method:

```
updateUserProfile() {
            this.$store.dispatch("user/updateProfile", this.form.profile);
        }
```

Everything works perfect. On my store dispatch I make the API call and update the store via my mutation:

```
context.commit('UPDATE_PROFILE', profile);
```

No errors until this step.

But if I change the form input again - after I pressed the submit button, I get:

> vuex: do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation

But I don't want to change the vuex store just when I change the value on my form input.
It should only be updated if someone hits the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

`v-model` provides 2-way data binding. Changing anything in the view will automatically attempt to update the model directly, rather than through a mutation. Thankfully, Vue allows `get` and `set` on computed properties to help us past that.

What you should do on your textfield component is add a computed property with `get` and `set` methods. It will look something like this:

```js
computed: {
  userProfile: {
    get() {
      JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.getters["user/Profile"]));
    },
    set() {
      // only commit the changes to the form, do not submit the action that calls the API here. 
      this.$store.commit("user/updateProfile", this.form.profile) 
    }
}
```

Your v-model attribute should then be set to this newly created property, and any 'set' operations (read: a user changing the input value) will call the action as opposed to attempting to set the value in the Store directly.

Here is a live example: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Qumez/pen/XWWPamO)

Comment: thank you for your answer.
if i do it this way, then even a change on a textfield will trigger the dispatch, am i right?

what i want is, that the user have to submit the form via my submit button.
how can i reach this?

Comment: You're correct. My apologies for missing that bit in your post. In this case, the action will be called every time the input changes, and if the action is responsible for making calls with the form data... well you're going to be making a lot of calls :) SO - to fix that, you'll want to only commit the mutation in the set() handler of your computed property. Then, add an @click handler on your submit button to submit the user/updateProfile action. If you haven't created a mutation to update the profile in the state, you'll need to do that. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer.
But i even dont want to commit the changes to the store.

The API and the store should only be updated if the users hits the submit button.
How can i archieve this?

Comment: Oh, in that case, you'll just need to remove the v-model directive and only call the commit and dispatch when you click submit!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
form: {
    profile: _.cloneDeep(this.$store.getters['user/Profile'])
  },
```

and added a watch handler:

```
form: {
            handler: _.debounce(function (form) {
                console.log("watch fired");
            }, 500), deep: true
        }
```

so if the user changes the value, nothing happens (except my console.log action).
if he presses the submit button, the store dispatch action will be fired.